# Optional/Default parameter and params in method argument error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm creating a method with a default parameter and a params keyword to take multiple inputs in my method

```
public static string MyMethod(char input1 = '/', params string[] input2)
{
  //my logic
  return "";
}
```

Method Call

```
var getDataOne = MyMethodClass.MyMethod('/',"String1","String2"); // working fine
var getDataTwo = MyMethodClass.MyMethod("String1","String2"); // Not working
```

**Error**: Error CS1503 Argument 1: **cannot** convert from '**string**' to '**char**'

How do I resolve this. Do I have to get rid of default parameter?

Comment: Use an overload instead. Optional parameters should be used sparingly; combining them with `params` arguments leads to especially ambiguous situations.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah, That I get, but is there no other way offered by C# than to use overloading?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the default by wrapping your strings in an array beforehand and specifying it's intended for the `params` parameter.

```cs
var getDataTwo = MyMethodClass.MyMethod(input2: new string[]{ "String1", "String2" });
```